# PostgreSQL - Update current Partition range and Move data from Default Partition

Tags: postgresql

I have Partition  Mytable created with Mytable_default, Mytable_p2022_01 ( Date range from Jan-01-2022 to Jan-02-2022).
The Mytable_default Partition has data for Jan-03-2022. How Can I Update my current Partition Mytable_p2022_01 (Date range from Jan-01-2022 to **Feb-01-2022**)and move all data from Mytable_default Partition to  Mytable_p2022_01 from using partman.partition_data_proc SP.

Comment: What is the SP partman.partition_data_proc ? Can you share the definition of the partitions ?

Comment: @Edouard - It is inbuild Stored Procedure with Partman which take care some of maintenance.  https://github.com/pgpartman/pg_partman/blob/master/sql/procedures/partition_data_proc.sql